# Tongue drum note symbols

Tags: notation, drums, percussion

I've been offered recently a tongue drum similar to this one:

[image: Tongue drum, with eight tongues and numbers marked on them. The numbers are 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 5 with a dot below it, 6 with a dot below it, and 1 with a dot above it.]

Exploring the Stack Exchange answers, I think it is tuned to the pentatonic scale. However I cannot make sense of the symbols on the tongues, especially the '1' with a kind of dot added on top, or the '5' and '6' with a dot on the bottom of the digit. Can anyone help deciphering it? Which are actually the notes played by each tongue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers normally refer to the degree of the key in which it's tuned (usually C): 1 is the tonic (C), 2 the supertonic (D), etc.

The dots indicate if the note is an octave above or below the *reference*.

In the case above, assuming it's tuned in C, the notes are (from low to high):

- 5̥ : G (octave below)
- 6̥ : A (octave below)
- 1 : C
- 2 : D
- 3 : E
- 5 : G
- 6 : A
- 1̊ : C (octave above)

It's a pentatonic scale. With it you can play any tune based on C pentatonic major, or pentatonic minor using A as the tonic.

---

Download a tuner app (unless you have a physical one) and check whether the "1" is actually a C or not.  If it's another note, then that's the tonic.

For instance, if 1 is F, then  the notes are: C (5̥), D, F (1), G, A, C, D, F (1̊); meaning that you can play F major or D minor pentatonics.